# Django falis when invalid values entered for dates

Tags: django, django-forms

Im using two date fields in my model as follows.

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    checkin_date = models.DateField()
    checkout_date = models.DateField()
    ...
```

I use model form in my GCBV Create. I'm overriding the forms' `clean()` method to do conditional validation between fields.

```
class BookingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(BookingForm, self).clean()
        checkin_date = self.cleaned_data['checkin_date'] # fail here
        checkout_date = self.cleaned_data['checkout_date'] # fail here

        self.validate_dates(checkin_date, checkout_date)


# GCBV Create
class NewBooking(CreateView):
    form_class = BookingForm
    model = Booking
```

When I enter invalid values (such as 2018-09-**31**) for either dates it just fail and stack trace is printed.

**Stack Trace:**

```
File "/home/indikau/workspace/projects/src/booking/forms.py" in clean
  67.         checkout_date   = self.cleaned_data['checkout_date']

Exception Type: KeyError at /booking/add/
Exception Value: 'checkout_date'
```

1) Is this the behavior for all form field validations and occurring only if `clean()` method is overridden?

2) How to overcome the issue without totally failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should get data from **`cleaned_data`** instead of from **`cleaned_data`**

```
class BookingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(BookingForm, self).clean()
        checkin_date = cleaned_data.get('checkin_date')
        checkout_date = cleaned_data.get('checkout_date')
        if checkout_date and checkin_date:
            self.validate_dates(checkin_date, checkout_date)
```

**Reference** : [Example of **`clean()`** method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)